# Nested Link elements not re-directing to a component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning React routing and so far have been able to implement the basic routing. Now, I have a table where the country names are printed with a link. When I click the a link (Country name) in the table, the url is adding the selected country name. However, I want it to open a new component which I have declared in the Index.js. But, it's not doing anything. Here is my code:

[Screenshot](https://screenshot.click/15-50-shqe2-v0lmm.gif)

[Screenshot of link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTSZm.jpg)

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import App from './App';
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Redirect

} from "react-router-dom";
import Login from './Login';
import Signup from './Signup';
import Home from './Home';
import Notfound from './Notfound';
import Country from './Country'




ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>



    <Switch>
      <Route path="/signup">
        <Signup />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/login">
        <Login />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/data">
        <App />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/data/:id">
        <Country/>
      </Route>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <Home />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/not-found" component={Notfound}/>
      <Redirect to="/not-found"/>

    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
  ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Result.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table';
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link

} from "react-router-dom";

const Result = (props) => {
  console.log('props value is:' + props.data)
  let { searchCheck, searchValue } = props;


  let update = props.data.map((item) => {

    const { countryInfo, country, cases, deaths, recovered, active, casesPerOneMillion } = item;
    let findMortality=Math.ceil((deaths/cases)*100);
    return (
      (searchCheck) ? country.toUpperCase().includes(searchValue.toUpperCase()) ?
        <tbody>
          <tr key={countryInfo._id}>
            <td><img style={{ height: '25px', width: '50px' }} src={countryInfo.flag} /></td>  
            <td><Link to={`/data/${country}`}>{country}</Link></td>
            <td>{cases}</td>
            <td>{active}</td>
            <td>{recovered}</td>
            <th>{findMortality}%</th>
            <td>{deaths}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody> :
        '' :
        <tbody>
          <tr key={countryInfo._id}>
            <td><img style={{ height: '25px', width: '50px' }} src={countryInfo.flag} /></td>
            <td><Link to={`/data/${country}`}>{country}</Link></td>
            <td>{cases}</td>
            <td>{active}</td>
            <td>{recovered}</td>
            <th>{findMortality}%</th>
            <td>{deaths}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    )
  })
  return (
    <div>
      <Table striped bordered hover variant="dark">
        <thead>
          <tr>

            <th>Flag</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Cases</th>
            <th>Active</th>
            <th>Recovered</th>
            <th>Mortality</th>
            <th>Deaths</th>


          </tr>
        </thead>
        {update}
      </Table>
    </div>
  )
}
export default Result;
```

Country.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';


export default function Country({match,history}) {
    return (
        <div>
            {match.params.country}

            <Button onClick={()=>history.push("/data")}variant="primary">Back</Button>  

        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: could be please create your code here `https://codesandbox.io/`

Comment: @SanatGupta It would be difficult to put it on Sandbox as the full app contains loft of pages and other files too.

Comment: That is what [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) examples are for. Many times, when reducing your problem down to the minimal amount of code to still reproduce an issue the problem (and solution) may become clear, in the least easier to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue:** You have a less specific route pathname listed *before* a more specific pathname

```
<Route path="/data">
  <App />
</Route>
<Route path="/data/:id">
  <Country/>
</Route>
```

`Switch` will only render the first matched pathname and "/data/sldkfsd" will match route "/data" before it matches "/data/:id"

**Solution:** Swap them (list more specific pathname first), or add `exact` prop to less specific route

```
<Route path="/data/:id">
  <Country/>
</Route>
<Route path="/data">
  <App />
</Route>
```

or

```
<Route exact path="/data">
  <App />
</Route>
<Route path="/data/:id">
  <Country/>
</Route>
```